# Wrong date format in the menu bar

Tags: macos, internationalization, system-settings

I set up some custom date formats, and while at first the date in the menu bar did honor them, now I've noticed it stopped and it's just using a standard one.

How do I switch it back?

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

If I click on it, it shows it using my custom format, but that's infinitely pointless.

I'm running `10.10.3`, IIRC I updated yesterday (from a `10.10.?`, likely the one just before this one), but I'm not sure it's *this* update who broke it.

Comment: Please show how you set it up

Comment: does my answer here help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181508/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin no, thanks. That's exactly what I have done and _do not_ work anymore. It works on other places, just not on the menu bar.

Comment: For the record, now I'm using `yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm • e/'w' – qqq,w`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the new behaviour in Yosemite and it can't easily be changed. The menu bar format now doesn't read your custom format and instead displays a barely customizable format instead. The only available options for it can be found in `System Preferences` -> `Date & Time` -> `Clock`.

One thing you could do is use a third party utility like `Day-O`, which is free and does exactly what you seek -> https://shauninman.com/archive/2016/10/20/day_o_2_mac_menu_bar_clock.

If you want things more natively, you could try editing the corresponding `plist` file directly (`com.apple.menuextra.clock`). I haven't however had much luck with it.

Open `Terminal` and type the following:

Reading the current settings:

```
defaults read com.apple.menuextra.clock
```

Setting them:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock "DateFormat" 'EEE hh:mm a'
```

Or 24 hours format with the (day of the) month and seconds:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock "DateFormat" 'EEE d MMM HH:mm:ss'
```

Then refresh the menu bar using:

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

Using `w` you should be able to add week number, but I haven't had any luck with that and it keeps resetting the week number.

Comment: Have you manage to get the `year` in there. `y MMMM dd`

Comment: `Day-0` is working, thanks! I'll wait a few days, just in case it breaks, but if it doesn't you'll get the bounty! I'm a bit perplexed by its author claiming he "won't update it for Yosemite", since it actually seem to work anyway…

Comment: It is mainly support for dark mode that it is lacking. If you don't use dark mode or aren't bothered by a weird UI in dark mode you should be fine.

Comment: As dark mode is now supported in v2 of Day-0 I updated the link

Answer (score 1):

Day-O 2 is the best app for this IMO.
https://shauninman.com/archive/2016/10/20/day_o_2_mac_menu_bar_clock

If you uncheck "Show Icon," it's basically identical to the default widget.