# How to change date format on menu bar without extra apps?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, internationalization, clock

This is how it looks right now

[image: This is how it looks right now]

These are my "Language & Region" settings

[image: These are my customization settings]

There is clearly a bug involved. I don't want use an app to solve such ridiculously simple prolem. It should be reading this format from somewhere right?

Comment: What an amazing language calls a day of the week `Pazartesi`? I like it. Oh, Turkish. Cool.

Comment: Anyone know how to get the date format mm/dd/yy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether you ever got the above method to work, but it never did the trick for me. However, I seem to have found a way that works without resorting to a 3rd party app. I was pulling my hair out about this because I wanted to have a '.' as the time separator, and even when using the `defaults` command like so:

```
defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock "DateFormat" "EEE MMM d  H.mm"
```

It would successfully assign the value, but every time I killed the menu bar, it would inexplicably revert to the default format. I'm not sure how permanent this will be, but I did a quick loop in bash and after running it for a few seconds, I killed the menu bar from a separate shell, and then returned to the loop and killed it - voilà!

So, basically from shell 1:

```
while true;

    > do;
    > defaults write com.apple.menuextra.clock "DateFormat" "EEE MMM d  H.mm";
    > done;
```

...then in another shell:

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

And then return to the first shell and kill the loop. I haven't restarted yet, but so far the change has stuck. HTH!

Comment: Thank you! I wrote a little sh script to set my format, works like a charm. This is probably not gonna last, but it's something.

Comment: Here is the script: http://pastie.org/10119105
Can be killed with CTRL+C after you see your format on menu.

Comment: Right on! Glad it helped...this one was vexing me for quite some time. I can't get it to persist across reboots. Sometime, if I am motivated, I guess I can use init or launchd to set it every time it boots...

Comment: Doesn't work for me, on OS X Yosemite. Running scripts/commands in that order removes the date from the menu bar, but then it comes back in the same old format. They break this stinking feature every stinking operating system update.

Comment: I am on Yosemite now, just run the script twice and wait for clock to come back before pressing ctrl + c. Not the best solution but works.

Comment: I recall this has worked for me in the past, but it's not working on a new macOS Sierra machine for me today.

Comment: Anyone know how to get the date format mm/dd/yy?

Comment: Confirmed. I'm currently working on dotfiles on High Sierra and this does not work.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Mojave either :( The amusing thing though is I don't want it the way the OP had it originally i.e. day first. The defaults shows the format right but it doesn't register even after the rest of the steps. And although I didn't check defaults after a reboot (at first) the preferences showed what I would have expected; but then I checked defaults and it was in the wrong order again (but preferences it was not). I also want seconds and that's not showing up. Seconds matter to me very much. Yet I thought before I played with this it was showing seconds.

Comment: I tried hacking this to add my short username to the menu bar (since my employer disables fast user switching and I like having the reference (my username isn't the same on every computer), but it wouldn't work... Is there a way to add your own characters?

Comment: Doesn't work on Monterey :-(

Answer (score 2):

There is a specific Pref Pane for the menu bar Clock settings, separate to the Dates pref, which is for how dates are shown in Finder.
**System Prefs > Date & Time > Clock**

You can also access it directly by clicking the menu bar Clock, or typing "date" into Prefs search

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I actually want to put MY preffered format. These options are not enough. No year, no way to show month as number, etc.. This should be a pretty trivial task with terminal. I just don't know where to look.

Comment: Then you should ask that question separately. My answer simply points out that you were setting the wrong pref for the menu bar clock.